# Idiomatic typescript to iterate foreach key of a StringMap<T>?

Tags: typescript

I'm using typescript 1.4 and declared a property `prop: StringMap<Foo>`. Are you supposed to do the javascript way of iterating over the object keys,

```
for (var i in prop) {
    if (prop.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    }
}
```

Or

```
prop.forEach(function(i) {
});
```

(which doesn't work in some old browsers), or does typescript define any special syntax for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't have any special syntax for this. Use whichever method you would use in regular JavaScript.

Comment: I notice the prop.forEach() comes up as a type error for me - I guesss because Html5.d.ts doesn't define a forEach operator on StringMap<T>.

Comment: `forEach` is a member of `Array`, not `Object`. A plain object `{}` does not have `forEach` in any standard runtime.